# Cannot implicitly convert type Interface to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>'

Tags: c#

stuck in below issue please help,
I have one below class and it contain one method with return type is interface

```
public class Helper
{ 
    public IRestResponse GetCam (string searchTerm, int page, int pageSize)
    {
       RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
                             {
                               RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
                               Resource = string.Format("/assets/campaigns?search={0}&page={1}&count={2}&depth=complete",
                               searchTerm, page, pageSize)
                              };

      IRestResponse response = _client.Execute(request);

      return response;
    }
}
```

in that interface I have some get set,

```
public interface IRestResponse
    {
        string Content { get; set; }
        string ContentEncoding { get; set; }
        long ContentLength { get; set; }
        string ContentType { get; set; }
        IList<RestResponseCookie> Cookies { get; }
        Exception ErrorException { get; set; }
        string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        IList<Parameter> Headers { get; }
        IRestRequest Request { get; set; }
        ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
        Uri ResponseUri { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now when I call Helper class in my another program like below it giving me error as :

> > "Cannot implicitly convert type 'RestSharp.IRestResponse' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

my calling program have below code

```
CamSample.Helper f = new CampaignHelper("Company name", "UserName", "Password", "SiteName");
IList<CampaignSample.Models.IRestResponse> q = new List<CampaignSample.Models.IRestResponse>();
//List<IRestResponse<CampaignSample.Models.Campaign>> w = new IList<IRestResponse<CampaignSample.Models.Campaign>>().ToList();
q = f.GetCam("", 1, 200);
```

--- getting the error here
Please tell me the solution

Comment: there are **a lot** of questions on stackoverflow regarding "cannot implicitly convert". Did you do any research and what was unclear with the research you made? If you explain what is unclear with the error message / the research you made, you might get a better answer that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is returning `IResponse` object not `List<IResponse>` object, you shoud be writing like this when calling:

```
CampaignSample.Models.IRestResponse response = f.GetCam("", 1, 200);
```

or you can make use of `var` here:

```
var response = f.GetCam("", 1, 200);
```